# Identify duplicate character in a String and replace it

Tags: java

Found a JavaScript assignment in Codewar.com:

> The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where
>   each character in the new string is '(' if that character appears only
>   once in the original string, or ')' if that character appears more
>   than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when
>   determining if a character is a duplicate.

Examples:

```
"din" => "((("
"recede" => "()()()"
"Success" => ")())())"
"(( @" => "))(("
```

I tried to do the assignment in Java, and came up with below code. I want to know is this the write way to code or is there a better way? If so please let me know.

```
private static String duplicateEncode(String word) {
    String encodeString = "";
    String decodedString = word.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedString.length(); i++) {

        if (decodedString.substring(i + 1, decodedString.length())
                .contains(String.valueOf(decodedString.charAt(i)))
                || decodedString.substring(0, i).contains(String.valueOf(decodedString.charAt(i)))) {
            encodeString += ")";
        } else {
            encodeString += "(";
        }

    }
    return encodeString;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for a code review, which is off-topic. Please check if your question is suitable and on-topic on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For working code that you've written where you're looking for an opinion on how "good" your code is, I recommend posting over on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). As with posting to any new site, please visit their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure the questions you ask there are on-topic and follow the site's rules.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Brain for pointing me to right site.

Comment: For future reference, OP [asked this question over on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189425/identify-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-and-replace-them).